# What is the script in javascript equals to $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] in php?

Tags: javascript

I want to pass a URL to another domain through javascript appending iframe, when exit the iframe, the other domain can return the user to previous page on my site. If use php to submit the exit_url, it is

```
$exit_url = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . "&request=example"";
```

I would like to learn how to convert this string to use in javascript. Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You get the equivalent of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` by appending `location.pathname` and `location.search`:

```
var request_uri = location.pathname + location.search;
```

Comment: what does location.search do?

Comment: @Jenny It's the query string. For example, `"?a=b"` in `"http://www.example.com/index.html?a=b"`.

Comment: I see. the querry strings are for the other domain. I only want to return to the previous page on my website. This page is not in the querry string that submitted to the other domain. so, do I still need to use the location.search?

Comment: @Jenny but your current page may already have something in the query string; not sure whether that matters, but you asked for an equivalent construct and this is it.

Comment: Thanks! I will try both, with or without location.search.

Comment: var request_uri = location.pathname + location.search + location.hash; Works better, because allow to catch a url like /path/?destination=/admin#anchor.

Comment: @RuslanP but that's not an equivalent, because hash isn't sent to the server

Comment: @Jack, sure, that's not an equivalent, but can be helpful in some cases ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
window.location.pathname.substr(1) will do it
```

Comment: what's the value of substr(1) ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question, but `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is basically `location.pathname`

Answer (score 0):

In case the search string is empty, you will want to append "?" instead of "&"

```
var q = location.search ? "&" : "?";
var request_uri = location.pathname + location.search + q + "other=value";
```