# substr with $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Is their anyway to copy such PHP function in javascript?

```
$uri = explode("/",substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],1));
if((isset($uri[0])) && ($uri[0]!="")) {$page = $uri[0];} else {$page = "home";}
```

Comment: See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12241138/what-is-the-script-in-javascript-equals-to-serverrequest-uri-in-php

Comment: @MarcB - would you mind showing me an example please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
var uri = location.pathname.substr(1).split('/');
if(0 in uri && uri[0] != "") {
    var page = uri[0];
} else {
    var page = "home";
}
```

And a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Zrc8/1) to show this in action.

Comment: That will give you "https:", why not use `location.pathname`?

Comment: Updated to use pathname, substr removes the leading `/`